# UiDevice object throwing error when we start Instrumentation using startInstrumentation() from main activity

Tags: android, junit4, instrumentation, android-uiautomator

I am trying to Access Instrumentation from an Android Application(By Launching App) using startInstrumentation();

My MainActivty code is below

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("package", "com.example.per.simpleuiauto");
        boolean returnValue = startInstrumentation(new ComponentName("com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test", "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"), null, arguments);
        Log.d(TAG, "returnValue: "+returnValue);
    }
```

Value of the returnValue shows "true" which indicates it(com.example.per.simpleuiauto) was launched

Problem is : once the Instrumentation starts and setUp() is called, getting NullPointerException at below line

```
mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
```

Complete code is below

```
private static UiDevice mDevice;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp: called");
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mDevice.pressHome();
    }
```

**My question is:**

1. Is this possible to start instrumentation test from android app without adb??
2. Any possibility to execute Instrumentation test by launching apk without pc connection??

(No adb wired or wireless).

Below are my adb crash logs:

```
 15:47:41.788 6578-6578/? I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Instrumentation Started!
08-31 15:47:41.794 6578-6578/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Setting context classloader to 'dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]', Original: 'dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]'
08-31 15:47:41.798 6578-6578/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/MonitoringInstrumentation: No JSBridge.
08-31 15:47:41.806 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto D/InfraTrack: Tracking disabled due to lack of internet permissions
08-31 15:47:41.806 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/UsageTrackerFacilitator: Usage tracking disabled
08-31 15:47:41.807 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRequestBuilder: Scanning classpath to find tests in apks [/data/app/com.example.per.simpleuiauto.test-2/base.apk]
08-31 15:47:41.921 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto D/TestExecutor: Adding listener android.support.test.internal.runner.listener.LogRunListener
08-31 15:47:41.921 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto D/TestExecutor: Adding listener android.support.test.internal.runner.listener.InstrumentationResultPrinter
08-31 15:47:41.921 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto D/TestExecutor: Adding listener android.support.test.internal.runner.listener.ActivityFinisherRunListener
08-31 15:47:41.924 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: run started: 2 tests
08-31 15:47:41.928 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: started: testAdd(com.example.per.simpleuiauto.CalculatorTester)
08-31 15:47:41.930 6578-6578/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 0
08-31 15:47:41.938 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: failed: testAdd(com.example.per.simpleuiauto.CalculatorTester)
08-31 15:47:41.938 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
08-31 15:47:41.941 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.UiAutomation.setOnAccessibilityEventListener(android.app.UiAutomation$OnAccessibilityEventListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiAutomatorBridge.setOnAccessibilityEventListener(UiAutomatorBridge.java:78)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.QueryController.<init>(QueryController.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiAutomatorBridge.<init>(UiAutomatorBridge.java:66)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.InstrumentationUiAutomatorBridge.<init>(InstrumentationUiAutomatorBridge.java:35)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.<init>(UiDevice.java:103)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.getInstance(UiDevice.java:262)
                                                                                 at com.example.per.simpleuiauto.CalculatorTester.naveen(CalculatorTester.java:32)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
                                                                                 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                                                                                 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                                                                                 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
                                                                                 at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2022)
08-31 15:47:41.942 6578-6596/com.example.per.simpleuiauto I/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a UiDevice instance if your test has not been started from `adb`.